# How to extract these links with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract the download links from `<a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" title="Pronunciation for " data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3" data-lang="en_GB"></a>`. I am succesful with `re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', str(content1))`.

I would like to ask for a method with `BeautifulSoup`, which makes my code requires fewer libs. Below is my full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('''
        script,
        .hcdcrt,
        #ad_contentslot_1,
        #ad_contentslot_2,
        div.h2_entry,
        div.copyright,
        div.example-info,
        div.share-overlay,
        div.popup-overlay,
        span.xr'''):
    tag.extract()  
   
content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))

sound_url = re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', str(content1))
print(sound_url)
```

and result of my method

```
['https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0071410.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/fr_bachelier.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/63854.mp3']
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you just trying to get the same output but without using `re` or is it something else?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm trying to get the same output with `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: There are about 30 mp3 links in that page - do you want all of them or is there a particular subset?

Comment: Check my answer @LAD

Comment: @JackFleeting Good question, I restrict to  `content1 `.

Comment: FWIW collinsdictionary has [an API](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/collins-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('''
        script,
        .hcdcrt,
        #ad_contentslot_1,
        #ad_contentslot_2,
        div.h2_entry,
        div.copyright,
        div.example-info,
        div.share-overlay,
        div.popup-overlay,
        span.xr'''):
    tag.extract()

content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))

sound_url = [link.get('data-src-mp3') for link in soup.select('a[data-src-mp3$=".mp3"]')]
print(sound_url)
```

prints:

```
['https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0071410.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/fr_bachelier.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/63854.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-US-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/AR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/PT-BR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/ZH-CN-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/HR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/CS-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/DA-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/NL-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/ES-ES-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FI-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/DE-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EL-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/IT-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/JA-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/KO-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/NO-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/PL-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/PT-PT-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/RU-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/ES-419-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/SV-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/TH-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/TR-W0037420.mp3', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/VI-W0037420.mp3']
```

Comment: I modify your code `sound_url = [link.get('data-src-mp3') for link in soup.select('a[data-src-mp3$=".mp3"]')]` to  `sound_url = [link.get('data-src-mp3') for link in content1 .select('a[data-src-mp3$=".mp3"]')]`, but an error appears. Is there a simple fix?

Comment: I mean `soup` -> `content1 `.

Comment: content1 is not a BeautifulSoup object and cant be handled with a css selector.

You can do a soup out of content1 with BeautifulSoup again
`soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content1, 'html.parser')` and then `sound_url = [link.get('data-src-mp3') for link in soup1.select('a[data-src-mp3$=".mp3"]')]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.